# How to resolve EOF in Athena? FAILED: ParseException line 1:6 missing EOF at '-' near 'cw'

Tags: amazon-web-services

My Athena query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cwmilenko.new1 ( `ticket-id` string, `amount_stake_one` struct ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         'serialization.format' = '1') location 's3://cw-milenko-tests/1507tick2.parquet/part-00000-bbab8f70-4758-4041-9f69-c17f21c916dac000.snappy.parquet'
```

Error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:6 missing EOF at '-' near 'cw'
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact query that is used? The error seems to be appearing because of a dash - in database name but you have removed it from the question Also you cannot create a table from absolute file path and you need it to point to folder which in this case is s3://cw-milenko-tests/1507tick2.parquet/

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes,it was Because of dash in database name. Athena doesn't read properly and error comes in.

Comment: I got it by looking at your other question and have posted an answer.

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parket3 (
         `amount_stake_one` double,
         `bet_event_etl_date`string,
         `ticket_id` string 
) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3://myparket/' tblproperties ("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")
```